# Corrupted Json in Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

im having a strange problem when receiving json results from the server. I have no idea what the problem is. The thing is that my String json result is corrupted, with strange symbols.

The result is like this (taken from eclipse debug)

Image :

[image]

Another strange thing that happens is that when I change the URL of the service to an alternative one, it works and the data is not corrupted. The URLs are the same but once redirects everything to the other.
The URL is use always is (example) `http://www.hello.com`
The URL that works is `http://www.hello.com.uy`
(cant post the exact link for security reasons)

The second one redirects everything to the first one, its the only thing it does.

I have tried changing the encoding to UTF-8 and it is still not working, here is the code (with one of the URLs commented)

I have also tried using Dev HTTP Client extension from chrome to check the service and it works fine, no corrupted data. Also, it works perfectly on iOS so i think its just and android/java issue.

DevClient:
[image]

```
try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 10000);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

        //String url = TAG_BASEURL_REST +"Sucursal";
        String url = "http://www.-------.com/rest/Sucursal";
        //String url = "http://www.--------.com.uy/rest/Sucursal";

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            String jsonRes = sb.toString();
            JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(jsonRes);

            return jObj;
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.i("Error", "Request failed: " + t.toString(), t);
    }
    return null;
```

Comment: use JSON lint for json .

Comment: print out  Content Encoding maybe response is gzipped or deflated

Comment: Indeed the Content Encoding is gzip, you can also see that in the image of dev client. Here is what entity.getContentEnconding().ToString() returned "Content-Encoding: gzip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

// check if the response is gzipped
Header encoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
if (encoding != null && encoding.getValue().equals("gzip")) {
    is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
}
```

Comment: Excellent!! This was it! Im still wondering why would one URL (the .com) return the content gzipped and the other URL (the .com.uy which simply redirects to the original one) would return it without encoding. Im also wondering why the rest of the services are not gzipped, this last might be something server related. P.D. sorry for not being able to up vote you!

Comment: No problem. I'm also not too familiar with the particulars behind gzipping content, but I had run into this issue before so I knew exactly what was going on.  Good luck!

Comment: Also, I'd look into using something like Volley (https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) for API related stuff, which I believe would take care of these issues for you.